# How can I check if a message is a reply and check the replied message content? (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, discord.js

Here's my goal:
Check if the message containing the command is a reply to other message
If it is then check the content of the message user replied to.
For example:
Message 1: Hello! How are you?
Message 2 (a reply to message 1): !command

Now I want my bot to check if message 2 is a reply and if it is, check and console.log contents of message 1

I'm using discord.js v13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`<Message>.reference`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reference) to check for a reply.

For example, to check if `msg2` is a reply to `msg1` and log the contents of `msg1`:

```js
if (msg2.type === 'REPLY' && msg2.reference.messageId === msg1.id)
  console.log(msg1.content);
```

---

If you don't have `msg1` and you need to find it, you can use [`<Message>.fetchReference`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=fetchReference) to fetch the reply.

```js
if (msg2.type === 'REPLY') {
  const msg1 = await msg2.fetchReference();
  console.log(msg1.content);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it inside a command handler?